# Implementing youtube bookmarks app on Android

Tags: android, youtube, overlay, mobile-application, bookmarks

I'd like to implement bookmarks app allowing to save a bookmark for a particular moment in a youtube video so that it would be possible to jump back to the given second of the video.
I'd like it to be seamlessly integrated with the native youtube app. Is it possible to create a transparent layer on top of youtube app so that I could add this kind of functionality? I mean kind of button in the corner of the screen allowing to save the exact moment of the video. To do that I need to know what youtube video is being watched and what is the moment? Is it doable?
I have no experience with android development, but I'm a skilled Java programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a link to a youtube video which takes you directly to a certain moment in the video: https://theyoutubevideolink?t=36m42s (Note everything after ?)

This also works on the current Android YouTube App you can click on the link and it will directly take you to the moment. So it is possible to simply save that link to an external overlay/database.

But before thinking about that you understand Root permission is needed to be able to do this as an overlay. If you are fine with this, it is doable there are many open source YouTube apps with changes made to them on XDA Developers for example, and a simple database addition can the trick for this.

[EDIT]

Well I just went on the YouTube app and you cant hold a time-link like for example on LinusTechTips new video on mobile if you scroll down to the comments you will see many comment showing 0:55 which if you click on can take you directly to that moment in the video. Because we cant hold or anything else than just click, You will need to re-write so you can highlight etc.. which is why i mentioned before about having root access since you cant install third party YouTube apps it has to be re-written and just made into another app. To start you off check this re-written YouTube app called SkyTube: https://github.com/ram-on/SkyTube

Comment: Yasin Amin, thank you for your quick answer. The tricky part for me is getting this youtube link from the level of my android app. To be honest I even don't know how to do that in the mobile youtube app. If you could show me the example code doing that, I'd be very grateful.